# How do I nullify or swap the % character out, so the comments are compiled as text?

Tags: tex-core, comments, opmac

I would like to nullify or swap the % character out, so the comments are compiled as text.  I tried the following, which did not work:

```
\input opmac
\input cs-iwona

\typosize[14/13] 
\margins/1 letter (1,1,1,1)in 


 \let\`%\|


Hello World

% A comment????

| A comment!!!!!



\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the catcode of %, e.g. to 9 (=ignore). If you want another character to act as comment change its catcode to 14

```
\catcode`\%=9
\catcode`\|=14

Hello World

% A comment????

| A comment!!!!!

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: ooh I was too slow:-)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks so much!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Is there a way to swap it with another character?

Comment: @AFeldman yes just make any character catcode 14 then it acts as a comment

Comment: I added the code to make the | a comment char.

Comment: What a wonderful answer.  And its very usefull!  For instance, I use the % character to put in planning and strategy information into my documents, allowing the comments to be printed out on interim copies can help check my work.  And this also works with designating several catcode 14 characters, so it can do a type of versioning.

Comment: What would be the safest characters, in the sense of not interfering with the normal operation of TeX,  to use as catcode 14? Other than "asdfjkl" etc.

Comment: @AFeldman - You may also want to check out the `comment` package.

Comment: @AFeldman the safest char to use as comment char is `%` ;-).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes.  I will use that exact char from now on ... :)  Thanks Mico.

Comment: There is one general problem with that advice which should probably be mentioned: If the document loads a package that itself loads helper files (which some do) then it is not guaranteed that those help files do not contain % assuming it being a comment char. Basically the above is a great way but is is no longer supported LaTeX as LaTeX does not "officially" support catcode changes at user level (and packages that do  such manipulation internally also often fail in edge cases)